# How to generate gcloud project oauth creds client_secret json file programmatically

Tags: java, authentication, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-oauth

I want to generate access_token which I have managed to do so with client_secret.json file but I couldn't figured out how to generate client_secret.json programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not provide an API interface for creating OAuth Client ID and Client Secret.

This must be performed in the Google Console.

Comment: what I want to do is to create dialogflow agents programmatically, for which I have to first create a project, create oauth creds client id and secret, generate access token from those and pass it to rest create agent call, but as there is no support for creating oauth creds can you please suggest any other work around? Thanks

Comment: Are you part of a GCP organization? If not then the first item must be done in the console also. Do you require OAuth User Credentials or will service accounts work for your use case?

Comment: no service account won't work, as the create agent rest call https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/agent works only with oauth. I have managed to get service account keys using java sdk but it's of no use for this call and can you please elaborate the organisation part? what that has to do with oauth creds?

Comment: Service Accounts are OAuth also. However, I have not used the Datfaflow API.

Comment: There are two types of Google Cloud accounts. Those that are part of an organization and those that are not. If you are not part of an organization then you must create new projects in the Google Console.https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations